Split text column into different column with the specific column name from another dataframe
I have two dataframe data1 and data2. Want to split data2[Text] based on the columns from data1. But I don't understand how to start with this problem;Please suggest to solve with code.
}
data1 = {'Pet': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'squrrel', 'parrot'],
        'wild': ['Lion','Tiger', 'Wolf', 'Bear']
         'weight':[c5,d10, s3, w11]     }


data2= {'id':[102,105,108,110],
         'Text':[cat dog bear w11, 
                li dog c5 parrot, 
                 wol cat s3, 
                 Tiger parrt d10]}



Expected Output: {'id':[102,105,108,110],
                 'Text':[cat bear w11, 
                        lion parrot c5, 
                        wolf dog s3, 
                        Tiger parrot d10]
                  'Pet': [Cat, parrot,dog, parrot],
                   'Wild':[bear,lion, wolf,Tiger],
                    'weight': [w11,c5,s3,d10]


How do you split? By what criteria? What are the steps in splitting? Please provide example and your attempt to solve problem. Also, what is Text column? Is it list of strings (strings as words or groups of words)?

From your data and expected output, what I think you want to do is the following:
Create a dictionary mapping_dict to map each item in data1 to its corresponding column name, then add new columns (Pet, Wild, Weight) to data2. Finally, create a mapping function map_text_to_columns that splits the Text column into items, maps these items using the mapping_dict, and assigns the values to the appropriate new columns while the remaining items are rejoined into the Text column. This can be done this way
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'Pet': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Squrrel', 'Parrot'],
    'Wild': ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Wolf', 'Bear'],
    'Weight': ['c5', 'd10', 's3', 'w11']
}

data2 = {
    'id': [102, 105, 108, 110],
    'Text': ['cat dog bear w11', 
             'lion dog c5 parrot', 
             'wolf cat s3', 
             'Tiger parrot d10']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

mapping_dict = {}
for col in df1.columns:
    for item in df1[col]:
        mapping_dict[item.lower()] = col

df2['Pet'] = None
df2['Wild'] = None
df2['Weight'] = None

def map_text_to_columns(row):
    text_items = row['Text'].split()
    pet_values = []
    wild_values = []
    weight_values = []

    for item in text_items:
        key = item.lower()
        if key in mapping_dict:
            col = mapping_dict[key]
            if col == 'Pet':
                pet_values.append(item)
            elif col == 'Wild':
                wild_values.append(item)
            elif col == 'Weight':
                weight_values.append(item)

    row['Pet'] = ', '.join(pet_values)
    row['Wild'] = ', '.join(wild_values)
    row['Weight'] = ', '.join(weight_values)
    row['Text'] = ' '.join([item for item in text_items if item.lower() not in mapping_dict])

    return row

df2 = df2.apply(map_text_to_columns, axis=1)

print(df2)

which gives
    id Text          Pet   Wild Weight
0  102          cat, dog   bear    w11
1  105       dog, parrot   lion     c5
2  108               cat   wolf     s3
3  110            parrot  Tiger    d10

or if you prefer the json format
json_result = df2.to_json(orient='records', indent=4)

print(json_result)

which is
[
    {
        "id":102,
        "Text":"",
        "Pet":"cat, dog",
        "Wild":"bear",
        "Weight":"w11"
    },
    {
        "id":105,
        "Text":"",
        "Pet":"dog, parrot",
        "Wild":"lion",
        "Weight":"c5"
    },
    {
        "id":108,
        "Text":"",
        "Pet":"cat",
        "Wild":"wolf",
        "Weight":"s3"
    },
    {
        "id":110,
        "Text":"",
...
        "Wild":"Tiger",
        "Weight":"d10"
    }
]

or as a dictionary
print(df2.to_dict())
{'id': {0: 102, 1: 105, 2: 108, 3: 110}, 'Text': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: ''}, 'Pet': {0: 'cat, dog', 1: 'dog, parrot', 2: 'cat', 3: 'parrot'}, 'Wild': {0: 'bear', 1: 'lion', 2: 'wolf', 3: 'Tiger'}, 'Weight': {0: 'w11', 1: 'c5', 2: 's3', 3: 'd10'}}

